# Rails 6.1.3 no routes matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

The page I'm requesting was actually created by react After that it redirects to the page but the view is blank When I refresh the page I get the routing error:
No route matches [GET] "/room/473042e0-c8f5-11eb-948f-51083af9da12"
This is my config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "room/:uid" >= "world#index", as: 'room'
  root 'world#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo (it's not `>=` but `=>`):

```
get "room/:uid" => "world#index", as: 'room'
```

Comment: Thanks I can also use ```get 'room/:uid', to: 'world#index', as: 'room'```

Comment: Indeed you can :)

Comment: If this answered your question, don't hesitate to validate my answer :)